# Need help understanding SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sum

I would like to see the results total the received column and only return the item id once with the total received. Can someone explain why this is not working and help me get to where I need to be?

EDIT - Id like the results to be

```
Item A - 65
Item B - 52
Item C - 150

instead of what I am getting currently:
Item A - 15
Item A - 20
Item A - 30
Item B - 10
Item B - 15
etc
```

THANKS!

```
select S.supplier_id,
   s.supplier_name,
   ph.po_no,
   ph.order_date,
   ph.location_id,
   im.item_id,
   im.item_desc,
   invs.supplier_part_no,
   sum( pl.qty_received) as received,
   pl.unit_price
from po_line pl
inner join po_hdr ph on ph.po_no = pl.po_no
inner join supplier s on s.supplier_id = ph.supplier_id
inner join inv_mast im on im.inv_mast_uid = pl.inv_mast_uid
left join inventory_supplier invs on invs.supplier_id = s.supplier_id 
and invs.inv_mast_uid = im.inv_mast_uid
where ph.order_date between '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-31'
and ph.supplier_id = '101315'
and ph.delete_flag != 'Y'
and ph.complete = 'y'
and pl.delete_flag != 'y'
and pl.cancel_flag != 'y'
and ph.cancel_flag != 'y'
Group by 
pl.qty_received,
im.item_id,
S.supplier_id,
s.supplier_name,
ph.po_no,
ph.location_id,
im.item_desc,
invs.supplier_part_no,
pl.unit_price,
ph.order_date
order by item_id
```

[image: Results]

Comment: It would be better if you post the desired result

Comment: @lamak I believe all of those highlighted items should have the same recieved value since all item_id's are the same

Comment: `ph.po_no` is different so these are different groups. Remove it from the `group by` and select list if you don't want to group on it. And same goes for OrderDate and possibly other columns too.

Comment: @Hillboy I can't be sure, since op hasn't explained what s/he wants, and the results are to be expected seeing the current query

Comment: *sigh*, if you want that result, then just do: `SELECT im.item_id, sum( pl.qty_received) as received FROM .......... GROUP BY im.item_id`

Comment: Isnt that what I am doing currently. (except I have more columns in my select statement)

Comment: Are you trying to see only one for a a unique item_id and with it one recieved? If so then you should minimize your grop by to just im.item_id

Comment: The "except I have more columns in my select statement" is the problem (or more specifically the additional columns in the group by). Which single OrderDate  should be picked for example?

Comment: @AdamWhite your grouping by so many colums. When it groups on all of those attributes only one has to be unique to create a new row

Comment: If i do that I get an error message saying:Column 'supplier.supplier_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: well, "except I have more columns in my select statement" is exactly what's the problem (and the columns on the group by of course)

Comment: @AdamWhite just do as Lamak says to do it then do another join to get those columns

Comment: @AdamWhite the columns on the `SELECT` that aren't inside an aggregation function must also be on the `GROUP BY`. So, for your result (that has 2 columns) you have to use the query I posted on a comment

Comment: @MartinSmith The order date really isnt imporant. I just need a total qty of each item id. If i comment out everything except Item ID and Recieved, i am still getting multiple results.

Comment: @AdamWhite I don't know what else to say, "I just need a total qty of each item id", then use the query I posted

Comment: @Lamak Thanks. Sorry for being such a noob.

Comment: @AdamWhite it's not a problem to be a noob, everyone was one at first. But you got multiple comments explaining the issue and you seemed to not be minding them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the aggregate is grouping on other, changing values that cause separation in your data.

```
select S.supplier_id, -- values are the same, but is this necessary in your result set; if this value changes, you would have the separation in your data
   s.supplier_name, -- cannot see in your picture, but these are likely all the same
   ph.po_no, -- values are different, is this necessary in your result set?
   ph.order_date, -- values are different, again, is this necessary in your result set?
   ph.location_id, -- values are the same, but is this necessary in your result set; if this value changes, you would have the separation in your data
   im.item_id, -- the primary grouping factor
   im.item_desc, -- the description of the primary grouping factor (should not change per record)
   invs.supplier_part_no, -- values are the same, but is this necessary in your result set; if this value changes, you would have the separation in your data
   sum( pl.qty_received) as received, -- the aggregate you are performing
   pl.unit_price -- we cannot see this in your picture, but this could also be a changing value that could cause separation in your data, is it necessary in your result set?
from po_line pl
inner join po_hdr ph on ph.po_no = pl.po_no
inner join supplier s on s.supplier_id = ph.supplier_id
inner join inv_mast im on im.inv_mast_uid = pl.inv_mast_uid
left join inventory_supplier invs on invs.supplier_id = s.supplier_id 
and invs.inv_mast_uid = im.inv_mast_uid
where ph.order_date between '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-31'
and ph.supplier_id = '101315'
and ph.delete_flag != 'Y'
and ph.complete = 'y'
and pl.delete_flag != 'y'
and pl.cancel_flag != 'y'
and ph.cancel_flag != 'y'
Group by -- the Group by clause should change with a change in the columns selected
pl.qty_received, -- the aggregate should also, likely, not be part of the group by clause
im.item_id,
S.supplier_id,
s.supplier_name,
ph.po_no,
ph.location_id,
im.item_desc,
invs.supplier_part_no,
pl.unit_price,
ph.order_date
order by item_id

-- an example of how this might look

select S.supplier_id,
   MAX(s.supplier_name),
   im.item_id,
   MAX(im.item_desc),
   sum( pl.qty_received) as received,
from po_line pl
inner join po_hdr ph on ph.po_no = pl.po_no
inner join supplier s on s.supplier_id = ph.supplier_id
inner join inv_mast im on im.inv_mast_uid = pl.inv_mast_uid
left join inventory_supplier invs on invs.supplier_id = s.supplier_id 
and invs.inv_mast_uid = im.inv_mast_uid
where ph.order_date between '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-31'
and ph.supplier_id = '101315'
and ph.delete_flag != 'Y'
and ph.complete = 'y'
and pl.delete_flag != 'y'
and pl.cancel_flag != 'y'
and ph.cancel_flag != 'y'
Group by
S.supplier_id,
im.item_id
order by item_id
```

Comment: This helps a lot explaining this.  THANKS.

Comment: No problem. Also, if you need to include other columns, think about using the MAX/MIN aggregate, but you are going to get the MAX or MIN record value, and it may not necessarily represent exactly what you need to return. So, if you choose MAX(ph.po_no), you will get the maximum po_no value in that column grouped by suplier_id and item_id (if you use my example).